# Was there a god called Tyrimnas or Tyrimnos worshipped at Thyatira?

Tags: greek, christianity, history, gods

I've seen a few Christian sources (such as [this one](https://godskingdom.org/blog/2015/12/thyatira-529-1517-ad/)) mentioning a god called Tyrimnos (I've also seen it spelled Tyrimnas) that was worshiped at [Thyatira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thyatira), but I have not been able to find any reference to this god in secular sources. Was there really a god called Tyrimnos or Tyrimnas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Tyrimnos (or Tyrimnus in the Latinized spelling) was indeed worshiped as a hero in antiquity. The chief evidence for him we have, I believe, comes from coins and inscriptions naming him. An [overview of some German articles](https://www.jstor.org/stable/45275752) in *The Numismatic Chronicle* from 1892 contains a brief description:

> Two new medallions of Thyatira. The importancee of these two coins, which are respectively of Severus Alexander and Maximinus, lies in the fact that they bear new and interesting representations connected with the cultus of
> the local god whose worship seems to have been peculiar to Thyatira. The name of this divinity was **ΤΥΡΙΜΝΟC** [which is "tyrimnos" in Greek - cmw]. He is usually figured as a youthful god wearing a chlamys, and with a double-axe over his shoulder, either standing or seated, or in a temple or on horseback. The figure on the new medallions differs from any of the above. Here he is radiate, like Helios, and on one specimen he stands in the solar chariot. Herr Pick is perhaps, therefore, warranted in drawing a distinction between this form of the god and that of the local hero Tyrimnos, who is never radiate. The latter in inscriptions is called Προπάτωρ Θεὸς Τυρίμνος, while the former is called Προπάτωρ Θεὸς Ἥλιος Πύθιος Ἀπόλλων Τυριμναῖος (Cf. *Corpus Inscr. Gr.* 3497, 3493, 3484, and 8500).